# Stable Cotangent

Tags: c++, trigonometry

Is there a more stable implementation for the cotangent function than return 1.0/tan(x);?

Comment: I assume you're problem with 1/tan is that its undefined at pi/2 when the function should return zero?

Comment: Doing the inversion is dodgy when close to pi/2 yes... I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`cot(x) = cos(x)/sin(x)` should be more numerically stable close to π/2 than `cot(x) = 1/tan(x)`.  You can implement that efficiently using [`sincos`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sincos) on platforms that have it.

Another possibility is `cot(x) = tan(M_PI_2 - x)`.  This should be faster than the above (even if `sincos` is available), but it may also be less accurate, because `M_PI_2` is of course only an approximation of the transcendental number π/2, so the difference `M_PI_2 - x` will not be accurate to the full width of a `double` mantissa -- in fact, if you get unlucky, it may have only a few meaningful bits.

Comment: Ok. I guess this is the best I can do. Also I learnt about sincos, which I must admit I had never met before!

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR No.

As a rule of thumb, when looking for sources of inaccuracy one should be concerned first and foremost about additions and subtractions, which can lead to the issue of subtractive cancellation. Multiplications and divisions are typically harmless for accuracy other than adding additional rounding error, but may cause problems through overflow and underflow in intermediate computations.

No machine number `x` can get close enough to multiples of π/2 to cause `tan(x)` to overflow, therefore `tan(x)` is well-defined and finite for all floating-point encodings for any of the IEEE-754 floating-point formats, and by extension, so is `cot(x) = 1.0 / tan(x)`.

This is easily demonstrated by performing an exhaustive test with all numerical `float` encodings, as exhaustive test using `double` is not feasible, except perhaps with the largest supercomputers in existence today.

Using a math library with an accurate implementation of `tan()` with a maximum error of ~= 0.5 [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place), we find that computing `cot(x) = 1.0 / tan(x)` incurs a maximum error of less than 1.5 ulp, where the additional error compared to `tan()` itself is contributed by the rounding error of the division.

Repeating this exhaustive test over all `float` values with `cot(x) = cos(x) / sin(x)`, where `sin()` and `cos()` are computed with a maximum  error of ~= 0.5 ulp, we find that the maximum error in `cot()` is less than 2.0 ulps, so slightly larger. This is easily explained by having three sources of error instead of two in the previous formula.

Lastly, `cot(x) = tan (M_PI_2 - x)` suffers from the issue of subtractive cancellation mentioned earlier when `x` is near M_PI_2, and from the issue that in finite-precision floating-point arithmetic, `M_PI_2 - x == M_PI_2` when `x` is sufficiently small in magnitude. This can lead to very large errors that leave us with no valid bits in the result.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the angle between two vectors (`v` and `w`), you can also obtain the cotangent as follow (using [Eigen::Vector3d](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html)):

```
inline double cot(Eigen::Vector3d v, Eigen::Vector3d w) { 
    return( v.dot(w) / (v.cross(w).norm()) ); 
};
```

With theta the angle between `v` and `w`, the above function is correct because:

- |v x w| = |v|.|w|.sin(theta)
- v . w  = |v|.|w|.cos(theta)
- cot(theta) = cos(theta) / sin(theta) = (v . w) / |v x w|